# Decrease execution time using openMP

Tags: optimization, c, hpc

I have this method which computes the Fibonacci function:

```
long optimized_p_fib(long n)
{
    long i, j;
    if(n < 2)
        return n;

    #pragma omp task shared (i)
    {
        i = p_fib(n-1);
    }
    #pragma omp task shared (j)
    {
        j = p_fib(n-2);
    }        
    #pragma omp taskwait

    return (i+j);
}
```

The execution time of this method is **2.527737**.
I want to use tasks in OpenMP so that the execution time will be smaller, below is what I did so far, but the execution time got bigger (**4.039427**) compared to the method above.

```
long optimized_p_fib(int n)
{
    long i, j;
    if(n < 2)
        return n;

    #pragma omp single nowait
    {
        #pragma omp task shared (i) firstprivate(n)
        {
            i = optimized_p_fib(n-1);
        }
        #pragma omp task shared (j) firstprivate(n)
        {
            j = optimized_p_fib(n-2);
        }
    }
    #pragma omp taskwait

    return (i+j);
}
```

What could I possibly optimize my code, so that the execution time would get small ?

Comment: What kind of $n$ (Fibonacci number) and number of threads $T$ are we talking about? (for the timings you have provided) How does the timings increase\decrease with changing $n$ and/or $T$? That might give you a hint on what exactly is going on with your code and parallelization strategy.

Comment: So I am trying it with the n=35 and threadNumber=4, so while I increase the thread number the timing  increases

Comment: The recursive algorithm that you're using needlessly recomputes values of fib(k) many times for k between 1 and n.  You can vastly improve the performance of this by using a different algorithm that avoids this wasted effort.

Comment: Well, I would change the algorithm but this is a task where I just have to change the openMP commands and leave the algorithm as it is. So my problem is that I don't really know what else to use in openMP so that the time will get small

Comment: It's probably the overhead from managing the tasks at small $n$—not something to do specifically with OpenMP, but multithreading in general, so there probably wouldn't be a specific OpenMP construct that fixes this. Try to avoid creating very small cheap tasks.

Comment: @Kirill I have to do it with the tasks as an assignment

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm you are using spawns extremely cheap tasks, especially at small $n$. As you don't have a luxury of changing the algorithm, the only reasonable (relatively) way to avoid the overhead of creating cheap tasks would be to introduce another `if`-condition near the bottom of the recursion tree.

So, now you have a baseline case at $n<2$ (simply `return n`). I suggest you add another `if`-condition for $n<k$, at first trying $k<\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$, for which the value of the function will be calculated without spawning OpenMP tasks.

One other thing is that you forgot to add the line

```
#pragma omp parallel
```

before the section

```
#pragma omp single nowait
```

Such `#pragma` causes all of the threads in the pool to execute the next block of code. This might shave off a little bit of the timing in the second version code and make the execution time closer to the first one.

I would also suggest the following webpage about basic [OpenMP+Tasks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenMP/Tasks) where you might find an appropriate balance between *still following the assignment* and *making the most out of the computation*.